# Is there any ways to support usdt probes(User-level Statically Defined Tracing) without recompiling?

Tags: trace, perf

I want to trace mysql query event using ebpf tools such as [bcc](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-10-12/linux-bcc-nodejs-usdt.html), bpftrace and [perf](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#USDT). And I find that we need to compile the application ourself using a --with-dtrace flag to support USDT events. And how does usdt works. Is there other way to use usdt without recompiling the application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *dynamic* tracepoints with [`perf probe`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/perf-probe). These tracepoints can be defined in any executable or shared library as well as the kernel.

For example:

```
./perf probe -x /path/to/exectuable function_name
```

They are then available as tracepoints for `perf` and friends. You can also add function parameters or local variables if the optimization level permits.